# How to select faces of a mesh and apply extrude using a python script

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I am writing a python script to make a chair. I need to use the loopcut_slide() after that the extrude operators.  here is my code

```
    import bpy
import time
import mathutils
from mathutils import Vector
import numpy as np
start_time=time.time
from mathutils import *
from math import *
import random
D = bpy.data
C = bpy.context
#Clean the scene
bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
#bpy.ops.object.delete()
bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='CAMERA')
bpy.ops.object.delete()
bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='LAMP')
bpy.ops.object.delete()
def view3d_find( return_area = False ):
    # returns first 3d view, normally we get from context
    for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            v3d = area.spaces[0]
            rv3d = v3d.region_3d
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    if return_area: return region, rv3d, v3d, area
                    return region, rv3d, v3d
    return None, None

#make a chair
D.objects["Cube"].scale[0] = .2
D.objects["Cube"].scale[1] = .2
D.objects["Cube"].scale[2] = 0.005

D.objects["Cube"].location[0] = 0
D.objects["Cube"].location[1] = 0
D.objects["Cube"].location[2] = 0

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

region, rv3d, v3d, area = view3d_find(True)
override = {
    'scene'  : bpy.context.scene,
    'region' : region,
    'area'   : area,
    'space'  : v3d
}

bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(override,MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":1, "smoothness":0, "falloff":'INVERSE_SQUARE', "edge_index":11, "mesh_select_mode_init":(True, False, False)}, TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":-0.9, "single_side":False, "mirror":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "correct_uv":False, "release_confirm":False})
bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(override,MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":1, "smoothness":0, "falloff":'INVERSE_SQUARE', "edge_index":11, "mesh_select_mode_init":(True, False, False)}, TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":-0.9, "single_side":False, "mirror":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "correct_uv":False, "release_confirm":False})
bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(override,MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":1, "smoothness":0, "falloff":'INVERSE_SQUARE', "edge_index":18, "mesh_select_mode_init":(True, False, False)}, TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":-0.9, "single_side":False, "mirror":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "correct_uv":False, "release_confirm":False})
bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(override,MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":1, "smoothness":0, "falloff":'INVERSE_SQUARE', "edge_index":18, "mesh_select_mode_init":(True, False, False)}, TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":0.9, "single_side":False, "mirror":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "correct_uv":False, "release_confirm":False})


bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, -0.191221), "constraint_axis":(False, False, True), "constraint_orientation":'NORMAL', "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED', "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False})


Now, I need to select faces and apply the extrude operator.
```

1) How to set the face select mode.
2) and how to select the 4 faces as shown in the figure below

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a complete answer as it does not result in a complete chair but it covers the trickery you seem to need.

There are a few snafoos as I've copy/pasted from my own code base which treats a few features not present in your problem, it's useful code however so have at it I say.

The code is cut up so that I can describe what I'm doing but really it is a single script. So stitch it together and run it in blender then the chair button will appear at the base of the `add mesh` menu. Usefully I've split it up so that it may be made into a package aswell. So if you made each part into it's own file and resolved the imports as necessary you would have the start of a package. The double hash comments indicate what I'd call each file.

### Imports

Imports gotta have imports. I use the `bpy_extras` methods as it provides you with a proper Scaling/Rotating/Translating `matrix`. It also does object/mesh (a.k.a data) registration within the scene. In prior question(s) of my own the more experienced guys indicated that they don't use this helper, I figure this gives the blender team some control over object creation in packages and therefore I use it. The rest of the imports are pretty standard stuff.

```
import bpy
import bpy_extras
import bmesh
from math      import *
from mathutils import *
```

### Data

I do not fully utilize it here but these two methods allow for re-entrancy. That is you can edit the mesh after you've done something that breaks the history's breadcrumb trail. Usually I add an `Edit Panel` to facilitate this.

```
## utilities.py
def prop2data(prop, data) :
    """
    prop2data

    Given a PropertyGroup and ID-Data populate the latter from the former
    """
    for key in prop.rna_type.properties.keys() :
        if key in ["rna_type"] :
           continue
        if isinstance(getattr(prop, key), bpy.types.PropertyGroup) :
            if key not in data :
                data[key] = {}
            prop2data(getattr(prop, key), data[key])
        else:
            data[key] = getattr(prop, key)
            #print("{} : {} -> {}".format(key,getattr(prop, key),data[key]))

def data2prop(prop, data) :
    """
    data2prop

    Given a PropertyGroup and ID-Data populate the former from the latter
    """
    # The order of arguments matches prop2data this is deliberate and 
    # indicates that the structure is traversed according to Property-
    # Group rather then ID-Data (Which should be preferred).
    for key in prop.rna_type.properties.keys() :
        if key in ["rna_type"] :
           continue
        if isinstance(getattr(prop, key), bpy.types.PropertyGroup) :
            if key in data and isinstance(data[key], dict):
                data2prop(getattr(prop, key), data[key])
        else:
            #print("{} : {} <- {}".format(key, data[key], getattr(prop, key)))
            setattr(prop, key, data[key])
```

### Properties

I wrap all the properties for a given geometry into a pointer class for various purposes. It's helpful to pass these parameters into the `data2prop` and `prop2data` methods and to toss them into the geometry method for example.

```
## Properties
class chairProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup) :
    """Chair properties"""
    height     = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
                 name        = "Height",
                 description = "The total height",
                 default     =      1.0,
                 min         =      0.0,
                 #update      = _height_,
                 unit        = 'LENGTH')
    length     = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
                 name        = "Length",
                 description = "The total length",
                 default     =       3.5,
                 min         =       0.0,
                 unit        =  'LENGTH')
    width      = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
                 name        = "Width",
                 description = "The total width",
                 default     =       2.5,
                 min         =       0.0,
                 unit        =  'LENGTH')
    inset      = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
                 name        = "Inset depth",
                 description = "The depth of the inset",
                 default     =       0.5,
                 min         =       0.0,
                 unit        =  'LENGTH')
```

### Geometry

This next section has quite a bit going on. Firstly we provide stock unit vectors lying along the principle axes. This is largely done so that you're not dropping plus and minus signs everywhere.

The `selectPlane` method does most of the magic, I wrap it into a function so I can cherry pick verts, edges or faces. One can then make sub-selections of that selection to decide what is or isn't extruded.

`clearGeometry` simply strips out any mesh data while preserving the object and object.data (mesh) data blocks.

`chairGeometry` populates the `object.data` with the geometry you require. Here you should note that when `selectPlane` is called you must use a `location` and `normal` vector that are rotated with the object's co-ordinates, the way you do this is different. For the location you're flinging a point about in 3 space. For the normal you're taking one of those principle vectors and flinging it about in 3 space, you then need to re-center it about a zero by subtracting a zero that you also flung about in 3 space. Finally the last trick is in the selections by using sets, `fx` and `fy` you can make sub-selections using set theory. `fx&fy` in this case selects the corner faces, 'fx|fy' would select the skirt, `fx|fy-fx&fy` the edges and 'go-fx|fy' would get the center. This provides quite a lot of flexibility. For the rest there is a little algebraic trickery to make the center of the object coincide with the base of the chair once everything is extruded. This is also used to select the appropriate faces.

```
## geometry.py
AXES = {'+X':Vector(( 1,0,0)), '+Y':Vector((0, 1,0)), '+Z':Vector((0,0, 1)),
        '-X':Vector((-1,0,0)), '-Y':Vector((0,-1,0)), '-Z':Vector((0,0,-1))}

def selectPlane(bm, normal = 'z', location = Vector((0,0,0)), feature = 'verts', tolerance = 0.1) : # bpy.context.active_object.location
    '''
    Select all the geometry within a plane described by a position and a normal
    '''
    normal = normal if isinstance(normal, Vector) else AXES[normal.upper()]
    if isinstance(feature, list) :
       return {key : planeSelect(bm, normal, feature, location, tolerance) for key in feature}
    else : 
       return {'verts' : [vert for vert in bm.verts if abs(vert.co.__sub__(location).dot(normal)) < tolerance],
               'edges' : [], 
               'faces' : [face for face in bm.faces if all([abs(vert.co.__sub__(location).dot(normal)) < tolerance for vert in face.verts])]}[feature]

def clearGeometry(sc, ob, me, ps):
    '''
    I understand to be the best method of clearing the mesh data
    '''
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    me.update()
    sc.update()

def chairGeometry(sc, ob, me, ps, matrix = Matrix.Identity(4)) :
    '''
    Create a Chair Shape
    '''
    bm = bmesh.new()
    # Provide Geomerty
    bmesh.ops.create_cube(bm, size=1.0, matrix=Matrix([[ps.length,       0,                   0,0],
                                                       [        0,ps.width,                   0,0],
                                                       [        0,       0,ps.height - ps.inset,0],
                                                       [        0,       0,                   0,1]]))
    # Lower Geometry
    cx = [-ps.length/2+ps.inset,ps.length/2-ps.inset]
    for x in cx :
        go = selectPlane(bm, 
                         normal   = matrix*AXES['-Z'] - matrix*Vector((0,0,0)), 
                         location = matrix*Vector((0, 0, -(ps.height - ps.inset)/2)),
                         feature  = 'faces')
        go = list({item for face in go for item in [face] + face.verts[:] + face.edges[:]})
        go = bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm, geom=go, plane_co=(x,0,0), plane_no=(1,0,0))
    cy = [-ps.width/2+ps.inset,ps.width/2-ps.inset]
    for y in cy :
        go = selectPlane(bm, 
                         normal   = matrix*AXES['-Z'] - matrix*Vector((0,0,0)), 
                         location = matrix*Vector((0, 0, -(ps.height - ps.inset)/2)),
                         feature  = 'faces')
        go = list({item for face in go for item in [face] + face.verts[:] + face.edges[:]})
        go = bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm, geom=go, plane_co=(0,y,0), plane_no=(0,1,0))
    go = selectPlane(bm, 
                     normal   = matrix*AXES['+Z'] - matrix*Vector((0,0,0)), 
                     location = matrix*Vector((0, 0, -(ps.height - ps.inset)/2)),
                     feature  = 'faces')
    fx = {face for face in go if any([v.co.x < min(cx) or v.co.x > max(cx) for v in face.verts])}
    fy = {face for face in go if any([v.co.y < min(cy) or v.co.y > max(cy) for v in face.verts])}
    # the next line is useful if the bmesh operator needs faces, edges and verts
    #go = [i for s in {[face] + face.edges[:] + face.verts[:] for face in fx|fy} for i in s] 
    go = bmesh.ops.extrude_face_region(bm, geom=list(fx&fy))['geom']
    for v in list({item for item in go if isinstance(item,bmesh.types.BMVert)}) : v.co.z-= ps.inset
    # Update the Object
    bmesh.ops.transform(bm, matrix=Matrix.Translation((0,0,ps.height/2 + ps.inset/2))*matrix, verts=bm.verts)
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    bm.free()
    me.update()
```

### Operator

Next we provide the operator blender will call. This really just wraps the Create/Review/Update/Delete Geometry methods in blender specific boilerplate.

```
## operators.py
class MESH_OT_primitive_chair_add(bpy.types.Operator, bpy_extras.object_utils.AddObjectHelper):
    """Creates and Modifies a simple Chair"""
    bl_idname      = "mesh.primitive_chair_add"
    bl_label       = "Add Chair"
    bl_description = "This operator creates a Chair"
    bl_options     = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    part           = "Furniture:Chair"

    instantiate = bpy.props.BoolProperty(   name        = "New Object",
                                            description = "Used internally to control Object Creation versus Modification. See Object Creation in the Project Readme",
                                            default     = True,
                                            options     = {'HIDDEN'})
    dimensions  = bpy.props.PointerProperty(name        = "Dimensions",
                                            type        = chairProperties)

    def execute(self, context):
        if not self.instantiate and context.active_object and 'part' in context.active_object.data.keys() :
            sc = context.scene
            ob = context.active_object
            me = ob.data
            ps = self.dimensions
            data2prop(ps, me['size'])
            clearGeometry(sc, ob, me, me['size'])
        else :
            sc = context.scene
            me = bpy.data.meshes.new(name="Chair")
            od = bpy_extras.object_utils.object_data_add(context, me, operator=self)
            ob = od.object
            ps = self.dimensions # Using either od.object.GEOMETRY (Object Registered Properties) or self.GEOMETRY (Operator Registered Properties) os sc.GEOMETRY (Scene Registered Properties)
            me['ID']   = 'Not Used'   
            me['part'] = self.part,
            me['size'] = {} # Localized Data Store
        # Dimensions     
        # Your would adjust the properties here to ensure the various contraints are met
        # Geometry
        prop2data(ps, me['size'])
        chairGeometry(sc, ob, me, ps)
        return {"FINISHED"}
```

### Interface

The interface consists of a button at the end of the `Add Mesh` menu. This is not really the proper place for this but it'll do.

```
## interface.py
def addChairMenu(self, context) :
     self.layout.operator(MESH_OT_primitive_chair_add.bl_idname, text="Add Chair")
```

### Registration

The last bit simply un/registers everything and provides the name of some one to shout at when it all goes pear shaped.

```
## __init__.py
bl_info = {
    "name"         : "Furniture",
    "author"       : "Carel",
    "version"      : (0, 1),
    "category"     : "User",
    "location"     : "View3D > Add > Furniture",
    "description"  : "This allows one to create various funriture, specifically a chair",
    "warning"      : "Alpha Release, may wobble",
 }

def register():
    # Properties
    bpy.utils.register_class(chairProperties)
    # Operator(s)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_primitive_chair_add)
    # Menu(s)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_add.append(addChairMenu)

def unregister():
    # Menu(s)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_add.remove(addChairMenu)
    # Operator(s)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_primitive_chair_add)
    # Properties
    bpy.utils.register_class(chairProperties)


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    register()
```

### Notes

This code sort of stems from [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/45216/20441) question if you want to understand it better. There is also now a related [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/62132/20441).